# When is each implementation of the Page Cache used?

Tags: neo4j

Looking at the Neo4j code, there's an API for the page cache and two actual implementations (disconsidering the one inside the kernel), the default one and the Muninn one. The documentation states this about the Munnin one:

*This implementation of PageCache is optimised for configurations with large memory capacities and large stores, and uses sequence locks to make uncontended reads and writes fast.*

Which led me to believe the two implementations were independent of each other, but when you look at the actual code, some parts of the API are only implemented in the default implementation (PageSwapper and *PageSwapperFactory*) and some others are only implemented in the Munnin one (*PageCache, PageCursor, PagedFile, PageEvictionCallback*).

Also, when debugging and messing around with some queries, I noticed the `SinglePageFileSwapper` (from the default implementation) received a MuninnPage (from the Muninn implementation).

So my question is as it follows:

If the two implementations aren't independent and some things are implemented in both (for example there are two implementations for the Page interface: *ByteBufferPage* and *MuninnPage*), how is it decided when to use which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Neo4j 2.3 there is only one implementation: the `MuninnPageCache`. In 2.2 we also had an implementation dedicated to the `ParallelBatchImporter` – the machinery behind `import-tool`.

The implementation in the kernel module is only for hooking it up to the lifecycle machinery of the database kernel.

So the `MuninnPageCache` is the only one being used, because it's the only one we have in the product.
(At least in 2.3 and 3.0)